# How can I convert an Unmanaged solution into Managed solution?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have a solution file (.zip) which contains an unmanaged solution from our supplier.

I also have an access of the instance of the supplier's CRM instance, but that instance doesn't show up the solution in the list as it is unmanaged one, and hence I am unable to export it.

It seems the supplier created the solution on other system, and exported it as unmanaged, and then imported that solution to the system on which he has provide access to me.

I want to import the solution to my target system but as a Managed solution.

Is there any possibility of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way of converting an unmanaged solution to a managed solution.

You can instead import the unmanaged solution to a temporary CRM instance (e.g. an online trial instance or a sandbox instance) and subsequently export it as a managed solution. This managed solution can then be imported in your desired target environment.

As I understand your question, the unmanaged solution has already been imported into a system you have access to, but the solution container itself has been deleted. The unmanaged customizations are still present in the system, no matter if a solution refers to them or not. In that case, you could manually create a new solution containing all the components and subsequently export that as managed.

Comment: I have already tried importing unmanaged solution in a different trial instance. but still the solution doesn't show up in the solutions list... Wondering if imported unmanaged solutions do not show up in the solutions list? In that case, we can't export them as managed solution

Comment: I have never heard of a solution that does not show up in the list of solutions after importing. That sounds like a fairly broken solution...

Comment: I think it was a default solution which was exported as Unmanaged from the original system. I got the access of original system, and created a new solution, added all components, exported the solution as managed, and imported it, and that worked.